# Scrapy FormRequest for multiple buttons

Tags: python, forms, button, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to get the second button from a form, but can't seem to get the FormRequest right.

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form action="/search/misc/set_serp_view" method="POST" class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-white active" type="submit" name="serp_view" value="serp-cards">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i> Prices
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-white " type="submit" name="serp_view" value="serp-grid">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Specs
        </button>
    </form>
```

I used this code,

```
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='nameCode'
    start_urls = ['https://octopart.com/electronic-parts/integrated-circuits-ics' ]

    def parse(self,response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formxpath="//form[@class='btn-group']/button[@value='serp-grid']",callback = self.scrape_pages)

    def scrape_pages(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

but it chooses **serp-cards** per default.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the same button over two different conditions? For example, sometimes a submission button is only available after text input in another element.

Comment: Already solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked like charm

```
    def parse(self,response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formxpath="//form[@class='btn-group']", clickdata={"value":"serp-grid"},callback = self.scrape_pages)
```